# Performance considerations - postmeta table versus new table for custom posts with foreign keys?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-query, post-meta, query-posts

I am modifying a plugin that uses various custom posts types. The types are

```
courses
   lessons
      topics
```

At `course`, `lesson`, or `topic` level there can also be `quizzes` and `assignments`.

ALso the plugin integrates with `bbpress` so that there can be `forums` and `forum topics` associated with a `course`. But only at course level. FOr that reason I added relationship field via the cool `pods` plugin so that when I add a forum topic I can tie it to lessons and topics. But there is still the retrieval question...

I often need to do actions such as

1. Retrieve all `quizzes` for `course` (meaning regardless if `quiz` was attached to `lesson` or `topic`
2. Retrieve all `quizzes` for `lesson` (meaning both from `lesson` and associated `topics`)
3. Retrieve all `forum topics` for `lesson` (meaning `forum topics` that are associated with a `lesson topic`.
4. Retrieve all `forum topics` for `course` (meaning `forum topics` across the whole course, which means those tied to `lessons` and `topics` of the `course`.

It gets really tiring having to always nest for loops just to extract everything I need.

Moreover, the way wordpress plugins uses the `wp_postmeta` table is a bit alarming. I don't the see the point to a given set of data having to be bundled in with every other plugin's data.

This has me thinking I should do away with all the plugin data that is stored in `wp_postmeta` and instead create separate tables for `course`, `lesson`, `topics`, `quizzes`, `assignments`. That way for a quiz, I can set `course_id`, `lesson_id`, `topic_id` so that I can readily retrieve `quizzes` tied to `course`, `lesson`, or `topic`. Likewise for `forum topics`. That means there will be duplicate entries in `quiz` table. Like

```
id  quiz_id  post_id    id_type
1      2       5        course
2      2       12       topic
3      2       21       lesson
etc
```

But I won't have thousands of quizzes! I can't think of a cleaner way to extract data I need at the level I need. I really am getting tired of `get_posts` with `args` that don't allow me to get what I need in single query.

Curious how others deal with this. I am coming from `laravel` dev where I loved the fact how for a model I could define `onetomany` and `manytoone` entities. That way I could do

```
$courses->topics
$courses->quizzes
$courses->forums
$courses->lessons->forums
$courses->topics->quizzes
```

It is fantastic working that way.

Lately as I work through wordpress I get the impression that this approach has so many roadblocks due to the nature of the `wp_postmeta` table.

But maybe I am missing something. Maybe `wp_postmeta` is some beautiful thing and I am not seeing the beauty.

So - can someone advise a good way to retrieve data in the way I am seeking?

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I can`t say this is the best solution but I know you can't go wrong with a structure like wp_postmeta.

I've done some custom work with GravityForms and they now use a similar structure. Instead of using postmeta there is an "entries" table. So with each form submission, there is an entry_id and multiple different entries differentiated by the meta_key. Knowing they switched to a structure like this probably indicates it's the best solution for queries.